# ip link cannot find device wlo1

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, iwlwifi

Nearly fresh arch install. Even though I did `modprobe iwlwifi`, after installing NetworkManager, it doesn't seem to detect wifi connections. If I do `ip link set wlo1 up` it outputs either `Cannot find device "wlo1"` or `RTNETLINK answers: Input/Output error`.

What can be done?

Edit: I downgraded the kernel, since this happened me on a different install before after a kernel updated. It still doesn't work, but now `ip link set wlo1 up` returns no errors, however it doesn't seem to set it up. After doing `ip link` I get this output:

```
% ip link                                                                                                                                                                                                       
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:d8:31:04:b0:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlo1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:02:c0:c1:1c:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: How have you figured out that your wifi interface is called `wlo1`?

Comment: @Kusalananda `ip link` outputted 3 interfaces: `lo`, `enp3s0` and sometimes `wlo1`. `enp3s0` is ethernet, I have no idea what `lo` is and was told that wifi interfaces start with w...

Comment: and if I try doing for example `ip link set wlan1 up` the only error I get is `Cannot find device` while this one sometimes gives a different error...

Comment: You may want to update your question with the actual transcript of you giving these commands and the exact output that is generated.

Comment: do you see errors in dmesg output when you execute these commands?

Comment: @brokenfoot yes there are a lot of kernel errors iwlwifi. This actually me before in other install after a kernel update, maybe if I downgrade it will work...

Comment: you can `dmesg -C` to clear kernel log, re-run your `ip` commands and `dmesg` to see errors specific to commands you are running. Depending on your kernel version, it might be a genuine bug - you can search here at [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&content=iwlwifi&no_redirect=1&order=changeddate%20DESC%2Cpriority%2Cbug_severity&query_format=specific)

Comment: Now that I downgraded the kernel there is no error when I do `ip link set wlo1 up` however after doing the command it still says to be down.

Comment: Your `wlo1` is in `state DOWN mode DORMANT `. You might want to change that with the `ip link set` command.

Comment: @C.W. I already tried that. `ip link set wlo1 mode DEFAULT` seems to work. However even after that, `ip link set wlo1 up` returns no errors but it stays `state DOWN mode DEFAULT`